# Spring + Tomcat URL white list to prevent command injection

Tags: security, spring, tomcat, code-injection

I currently have a webapp that consists of ~100 unique URLs + ~75 pages.  The application uses Spring for security and Tomcat to host.  My question is how do I prevent the following from happening:
`http://localhost/myApp/myPage;rollback;`

If that's not clear, what I am trying to prevent is my application from processing anything past `myPage` which would be found within a white list.  If this isn't  the proper way to go about this, what is?

***EDIT***

For the sake of completeness.  I am using Spring MVC.  What happens is the application passes the query string back to my application, processes the sql command (as it goes through the DAO).  We have resolved this by encoding the information that comes back through to mitigate this as best we can for the time being.

Comment: Why are you using semicolons in your URL instead of standard parameters?

Comment: Let's approach from the thought that my URL initially looks as follows `http://localhost/myApp/myPage`  then someone changes it to the following `http://localhost/myApp/myPage;rollback;`

Comment: @Woot4Moo  I think this is a design problem with your application.

Comment: @Rook most likely, it was someone's "hello world" in Java.  However, that does not change the fact that I need to eliminate its usage.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Some more details please. What exactly do you want to prevent happening - what goes wrong when someone tries to access http://localhost/myApp/myPage;rollback; ?

Comment: Woot4Moo - it is unclear what is wrong and what must be prevented. What happens if the user types ;rollback. What is your controller? Which version of spring? Using spring MVC, or another framework? Show some code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decided that the best course of action is to encode all data that is processed through the query string. Why this was not previously implemented is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a [custom filter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html) to the spring security filter chain to look for semicolons and filter away the request before it hits the servlet code.

Comment: I don't necessarily know if this resolves the issue, sure I filter away semicolons, but I'm only pretty sure there are more ways to send information across my server